# Unable to post custom attribute to LEAD field

Tags: salesforce

I do not have much experience with salesforce api. We have been using following api: `/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead` to post leads to salesforce, which has been working fine till now. We are already tracking first name, last name, email and company. 
Now we want to track one custom attribute, `gclid` too. We have added that as lead attribute on salesforce, but are getting following error even after allowing edit access to that field. We have tried adding `_c` suffix too, with no success. Any suggestions?

Error: `"[{\"message\":\"No such column 'GCLID_c' on sobject of type Lead\",\"errorCode\":\"INVALID_FIELD\"}]"`

We have tried various approaches as suggested when you google for above mentioned error. None have worked so far.

```
{
    'method': 'POST',
    'url': 'https://' + SALESFORCE_HOST + '/services/data/v21.0/sobjects/Lead',
    'headers': {
        'authorization': 'OAuth ' + sfToken,
        'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
    'body': JSON.stringify({
        {
            "Email": "nitin+28@gmail.com",
            "FirstName": "TestNitin1",
            "LastName": "TestBansal1",
            "Company": "WebEngage",
            "GCLID_c": "test gclid"
        }
    })
};
```

Any suggestions please...

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom fields' names end with `__c,` you have just one underscore in there?

Comment: Thanks @eyescream. That indeed was the problem. It needed to be double underscores. Thanks...